# How to make an string input from user into an array of the individual letters in the input?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, permutation

I am making a solution where the user inputs a word or just letters and it shows the permutations of the word without duplicates. How could i make it so the input is made into an array of characters.(I am modifying another persons code to try and do this) so I want to assign a given value where i commented SOMEHOW in my code below so that I can Split it into the array. Im new to coding and would appreciate the help.

```
public static void Main()
    {
                string input;
        //char word_inputed;
        Console.WriteLine("Please print a word");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        //string phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
        string[] words = input.Split(' ');

        foreach (var word in words)
        {

            foreach (var letter in word)
            {

               //SOMEHOW values = Console.Write($"{letter},");

            }
        }

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.AddRange(values.Split(new char[] { ',' }));

        char[] word_inputed = { 'A' };
        int n = word_inputed.Length;
        findPermutations(word_inputed, 0, n);



    }
```

Comment: `input.ToCharArray()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Microsoft sample

```
// Sample for String.ToCharArray(Int32, Int32)
using System;

class Sample {
    public static void Main() {
    string str = "012wxyz789";
    char[] arr;

    arr = str.ToCharArray(3, 4);
    Console.Write("The letters in '{0}' are: '", str);
    Console.Write(arr);
    Console.WriteLine("'");
    Console.WriteLine("Each letter in '{0}' is:", str);
    foreach (char c in arr)
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
/*
This example produces the following results:
The letters in '012wxyz789' are: 'wxyz'
Each letter in '012wxyz789' is:
w
x
y
z
*/
```

[door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.8)